# Why won't clear:both eliminate this overlap?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get `clear:both` to avoid having multiple floated elements colliding with each other. For example, with this HTML:

```css
.alignleft {
  float: left;
}

.alignright {
  float: right;
}

.alignright::before,
.alignleft::before {
  clear: both;
  content: ' ';
}
```

```html
<figure class="wp-caption alignleft">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/92x217&amp;text=92x217" />
  <figcaption>With a caption</figcaption>
</figure>
<p>Paragraph related to the left-aligned image with a caption.</p>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
<p>Below is a right-aligned image with a caption</p>
<figure class="wp-caption alignright">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/92x217&amp;text=92x217" />
  <figcaption class="wp-caption-text">With a caption</figcaption>
</figure>
<p>Paragraph related to the right-aligned image with a caption.</p>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
```

I'm trying to enforce that any paragraph as at most one `.alignleft` or `.alignright` image floating beside it, but the `clear:both` for the `.alignright::before` doesn't seem to be enough to shift the second figure down to start below the bottom of the `.alignleft` figure

I've tried assigning the `clear:both` class to the `.alignleft` elements, as well as to the `::before` pseudoelements. I'm not sure what other magic I need to try.

Because the HTML is created by the default WordPress editor, I'd really like to avoid any solution that requires a change to the element structure. I want to solve this strictly through CSS styles.

Comment: Generated pseudo-elements are _inside_ floating blocks, which have their own formatting context and don’t interact with their siblings. Try to set `clear:both` to floating elements themselves instead.

Comment: Some useful tips on floats and clear behavior: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: You could also try wrapping the figure and related paragraph in a tag that has a clearfix applied to it.  Here's a fork of your fiddle as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/60nkh9xr/

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn, technically, setting `clear:both` to the elements does what I said; it moves the `float:right` figure down so it's below the `float:left` figure. So, yes, I guess that's the answer to what I actually asked.

It doesn't move the related paragraphs (those that come after the figure in the HTML) so that they're still related. But then again, I guess the `float:right` of the figure is telling us they're allowed to be separate, so I shouldn't be surprised.

Comment: @dmbaughman I realize I can change the HTML structure to accomplish my desired goal. But because a third-party editor is creating the HTML, I'm hoping for a way to solve this strictly through CSS. It seems likely, though, that my goals may not be possible without changing the HTML structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the behavior you look for?

```css
.alignleft {
  float: left;
}

.alignright {
  float: right;
}

/* enforce that any paragraph as at most one
   .alignleft or .alignright image floating beside it */ 
.alignleft, .alignright {
   clear: both;
}
/* assuming that the paragraps are related to the figure before them,
   enforce that paragraps related to left-floated figure
   aren't beside the right-floated figure, and vice versa */
.alignright + p {
  clear: left;
}
.alignleft + p {
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<figure class="wp-caption alignleft">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/92x217&amp;text=92x217" />
  <figcaption>With a caption</figcaption>
</figure>
<p>Paragraph related to the left-aligned image with a caption.</p>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
<p>Below is a right-aligned image with a caption</p>
<figure class="wp-caption alignright">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/92x217&amp;text=92x217" />
  <figcaption class="wp-caption-text">With a caption</figcaption>
</figure>
<p>Paragraph related to the right-aligned image with a caption.</p>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
```

Comment: YES! `.classname + p` is what I was looking for.   Thanks, @IlyaStreltsyn